# forced line break after span coming from react, next or bootstrap?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, next.js

This is a bit of a mystery, I am wrapping some text in span tag and it is forcing a line break after it. I don't know if it is React.js, Next.js or Bootstrap, but I can't seem to remove the line break

Check out this page, it is the phone number at top of page.
https://wordpress-website-headless-v2-ep3x6ohy1.vercel.app/

I have already tried using Boostrap's `text-nowrap` tag, I also added `white-space:nowrap;` to every class. I assume React.js is doing this, but who knows.

html

```
<Col xs={6} md={8} className="text-right header-phone text-nowrap">
    <span className="phone-msg text-nowrap">To Purchase Artwork Call:</span> <a href="tel:416.450.5439" className="text-nowrap">416.450.5439</a>
</Col>
```

css

```
.phone-msg{
    display: block;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.header-phone{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 800;
    white-space:nowrap;
    }

.header-phone a:link, .header-phone a:active{
    color: #c65f0a;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 15px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.header-phone a:hover{
    color: #000000;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually the `display: block;` in your `.phone-msg` styles that's causing the issue, due to `block` generating line breaks before and after the element.

A possible solution would be replacing it with `display: inline` instead.

```css
.phone-msg {
    display: inline;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```